# Placemark image being stretched on Google Maps API application

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Has anyone else experience a custom placemark being vertically stretched and found a solution to it?

Example: http://www.mattpotts.com/so-stretched.png

And this is the code I have:

```
var blueIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
blueIcon.image = "images/beer-24x24.png";
var marker = new GMarker(point, {draggable:true, icon:blueIcon})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to set:

```
blueIcon.size = new GSize(24, 24);
```

along with customizing other properties of [GIcon](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GIcon). The stretching is occurring because `G_DEFAULT_ICON` is a typical Maps pin, and is something like 20x32.